# Recompile Django without restarting Apache

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I know there are topics on this and I am aware of using Daemon processes with mod_wsgi, but I am running on a Windows computer and I don't believe WSGIDaemonProcess is therefore available.  Is there any other way I can recompile Django without restarting Apache with mod_wsgi on a Windows computer?

If not that's fine but I just wonder how people would deal with this in a production environment with a hosting company (like GoDaddy), where the server is not theirs to control.  I'm running a development server so restarting it is no big deal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best you can manage is what is described in:

http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2009/02/source-code-reloading-with-modwsgi-on.html